# Scilab colors global / external variables

Tags: colors, global, external, scilab

I have a problem to detect global variables with scilab. In the parameters, by default "ExternalVariables" should be shown in red. However, variables defined in the function and outside both show in black and not in red... do you have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: "In the parameters"? What parameters? Where did you find it? Are you talking about syntax highlighting in SciNotes? You need to clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In Scilab, a variable can be inherited by all children functions (without being the argument list) and is unknown by all parent functions. **This is always true**. It's value will not change after leaving the children function (even if it's value can change inside), except if it's an output argument.

The syntax highlighting seems (by experience) to rely **heavily** of the state of the workspace at the moment you called Scinotes:

A variable will appear read if

- it's in your **workspace**
- and a variable with the same name exist in a file
- and if you open that file in SciNotes

Let's take an example:

Lets open Scilab and create a simple function with a variable that is defined in its scope

[image: first]

We see that it's not in red meaning that scinote is not aware of its global scope.

Let's close the editor, declare `y` in the console and open it again, but with the graphical button

[image: second]

Nothing as changed, because I think SciNotes is only aware of the state of the workspace at the moment it was called.

But if you open it with `edit` **or** if we close Scinotes (every tab) and open it again, then `y` will be in red !

[image: three]

I think `edit` may update the SciNotes knowledge of the workspace, whereas the button only display the file. Dunno why.